# How to find only unquoted array indices in PHP variable and quote them, using Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi I have several lines of code like these:

`$row[number];`
`$row[user];`

and I would like to transform them like this:

`$row['number'];`
`$row['user'];`

On notepad with Find and Replace using regular expression to find them I used this expression:

`\$row\[.*?\]`

You know how I could replace the same word by adding: `' '` to the extremes?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for non quotes in the index notations so replace `.*?` (which essentially says "anything") with `[^']+?`. You also can take the PHP definition for a valid variable and us that prior to the index notation to be more exact:

```
([$][a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*)[[]([^']+?)[\]]
```

you then replace with:

```
$1['$2']
```

https://regex101.com/r/GMrMEi/1/

If you wanted to go a step forward you could use a negative lookahead to exclude integers (`(?!\d+)`) indices (because those are valid in PHP):

```
([$][a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*)[[](?!\d+)([^']+?)[\]]
```

https://regex101.com/r/bU2sRg/1/

If it is only ever `$row` you can do:

```
[$]row[[]([^']+?)[\]]
```

and

```
$row['$1']
```

https://regex101.com/r/tTMmS7/1/